# Batch Select Sql in SQLite or SqlCE with C#

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-server-ce

Is there anyway to batch two different select queries to either SQLite or SQLCE and get the two result sets back in C#? If not, is there an embedded database that handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the queries with a semicolon and load the results into a `DataSet` or use `IDataReader.NextResult()`.

Answer (score 1):

Batching is not available in SQL Compact